# Bind multi select option in agnular2

Tags: rest, angular

Can anybody here tell me how to bind multi select? I get data from database (REST), using this part of code(in edit form) I foreach the categories and add property selected:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.group.categories.length; i++) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < this.categories.length; j++) {
                        if (this.group.categories[i].id == this.categories[j].id) {
                            this.categories[j].selected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And in template have this:

```
<label class="form-group">
                            Select categories:
                            <select [(ngModel)]="group.categories" name="categories" class="form-control" required multiple>
                                <option *ngFor="let c of categories" value={{c.id}} [selected]="c.selected">
                                    {{c.title}}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
```

If I inspect element, I see that angular set them value to selected, but didn't show to user which select box item selected.
What am I doing wrong? I didn't find any kind of solution so ask you. I hope that you can help me.

Comment: selected property has a string type, but in your code you set it to boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that someone be helpful.

Need to create array from categories that have specific object:

```
let selected_categories = [].slice.call(this.group.categories).map(a => a.id);
```

then add it to group object:

```
this.group.categories = selected_categories;
```

Then bind it in template:

```
<select multiple name="categories" [(ngModel)]="group.categories" class="form-control" >
                            <option *ngFor="let c of categories" [value]="c.id">
                                {{c.title}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

And that is that :) Enjoy :)

Comment: If you set your `[value]` to the full object as this: `[value]="c"`, you don't need to do nothing to bind it. It'll be automatically binded.

Comment: Well, can you show me how is the data that you're fetching from your server?